# Last child not working as expected with p tag

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with using `:last-child` with a certain class for my `p` tag, but works fine with other classed `p` tags, so here's my code:

```
<div class="port-container">
    <div class="header"><h1>Portfolio</h1></div>
    <p class="header" ref="who">Who am I?</p>
    <p class="info" ref="who">...</p>
    <p class="header" ref="what">What do I do?</p>
    <p class="info" ref="what">...</p>
    <p class="header" ref="projects">Current Projects?</p>
    <p class="info" ref="projects">...</p>
    <p class="header" ref="conntact">Contact me</p>
    <p class="info" ref="conntact">...</p>
</div>
<img class="bg-button pull-center" bg-toggle="false" src="./assets/icon-bg_white.png" title="Toggle Background" />
```

My CSS:

```
.pull-center {
                position:absolute;
                margin:auto auto;
                top:0;bottom:0;
                left:0;right:0;
}

div.port-container {
                width:975px;
                height:auto;
                overflow:auto;
                margin:auto auto;
}
                div.port-container > .bg-toggle {
                                background-color:rgba(44,62,80,0.25);
                                border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
                }
                div.port-container > div.header {
                                height:200px;
                                line-height:200px;
                                border:solid 1px #FFF;
                                border-top-left-radius:5px;
                                border-top-right-radius:5px;
                                text-align:center;
                                color:#FFF;
                }
                div.port-container > p.header {
                                padding:10px;
                                border-bottom:solid 1px #FFF;
                                border-left:solid 1px #FFF;
                                border-right:solid 1px #FFF;
                                color:#FFF;
                                cursor:pointer;
                }
                div.port-container > p.header:last-child { /*<----- Issue */
                                border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
                                border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
                }
                div.port-container > p.header.active {
                                border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
                                border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
                }
                div.port-container > p.info {
                                padding:10px;
                                border:solid 1px #FFF;
                                border-top:none;
                                display:none;  
                                color:#FFF;
                }
                div.port-container > p.info:last-child { /*<----- Works fine */
                                border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
                                border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
                }
img.bg-button {
                width:32px;
                height:32px;
                top:auto;left:auto;
}
```

*note: the ref attribute is used in my jQuery*

**tl;dr:**

**This works fine:**

```
div.port-container > p.info:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
```

**But this doesn't:**

```
div.port-container > p.header:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, common misconception of how last-child works. "The :last-child pseudo-class represents an element that is the last child of some other element." - http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p.info:last-child` matches all `p.info` elements that are also the last children of their parent.

In your markup, `p.header` are not the last children of their parent so while `p.header` matches various elements, `p.header:last-child` will match none.

Unfortunately, there is no `:last-of-its-class` selector. Matching is not possible unless you make some assumptions about the HTML structure. I made one:

```
p.header:nth-last-child(2) { }
```

It matches all `p.header` elements that are second last children of their parent. Note that this requires CSS3 selectors support.

```css
p { background: #CCC; }
p.info:last-child { background: #FC0; }
p.header:nth-last-child(2) { background: #FC6; }
```

```html
<div class="port-container">
  <div class="header"><h1>Portfolio</h1></div>
  <p class="header" ref="who">Who am I?</p>
  <p class="info" ref="who">...</p>
  <p class="header" ref="what">What do I do?</p>
  <p class="info" ref="what">...</p>
  <p class="header" ref="projects">Current Projects?</p>
  <p class="info" ref="projects">...</p>
  <p class="header" ref="conntact">Contact me</p>
  <p class="info" ref="conntact">...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `p.header` isn't the last-child ... it's always the `p` with class `info`.

> Selector is last-child (node) not last with class " "

The classname here just works as a conditional so if the `last-child` has the class `info` then style it.

To clarify if you have this selector:

> div.port-container > p.header:last-child

All are conditionals to target the element:

- If it's inside a container `div` with class `port-container`
- And it's direct child `>`
- And it's `p` tag with class `header`
- And it's the `last-child`

Answer (score 0):

You got the selector concept wrong.

The fact that you used a class selector does not filter the selection. In css, the combined selectors work as an `&&` condition, so:

```
p.header:last-child
```

Will target a `<p>` tag that is both an element with the class `.header` and also is the last child of its container.

**Unfortunatelly**

There's no way to get the last element of some class

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has stated your css selector will not work because `p.header:last-child` has to be the last child period. You can get around this by using jQuery.

CSS:

```
.port-container > .last-header {
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.port-container > p.header:last').addClass('last-header');
```